# Magento2: Reviews store

Tags: magento2

Anyone know any extension, thanks to which I will be able to create a category in website for customers to write an opinion about the store and I will be able to send an email asking for opinions after each order?

I do not mean issuing an opinion under all products only general reviews about the store.